# Finding stable natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

A natural number k is called stable if there exists k distinct natural numbers $a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$....$a_k$ > 1 $$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{a_i} = 1$$ Show that if k is stable then k+1 is also stable . Using this or otherwise find all stable numbers.

I can understand that this will be done by mathematical induction for natural numbers > 3 . But I don't know how to proceed with this sum.. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: such that summation of 1/a(i)= 1 from i=1 to i=k  is what ???????

Comment: Please check the edited one!

Comment: Are the $a_i$ ordered? That is do you require $a_1>a_2>\cdots a_k$ etc? If not you can just take $a_i = \frac{1}{k}$ and be done.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak the $a_i$ have to be distinct

Answer (score 6):

The induction step could be as follows:

You have for some $k$
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{a_i} = 1$$
so
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{2 a_i} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{2 a_i} = 1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{b_i} = 1$$
where $b_i=2 a_i$, $b_{k+1}=2$. Since the $a_i$ are distinct and $>1$, so are the $b_i$, so $k+1$ is indeed stable.

Comment: And what about "find all the stable numbers"... By the way thanks for the first part's answer

Comment: You have to find the smallest stable number, then all larger numbers are stable. Most likely you have to try a few small integers until you find the first stable one.

Comment: You might want to add the exception that this step does not work for $k=1$, as 1 is stable, however 2 is not.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak 1 is not stable, since $1=1/1$, so $a_1=1$, and the $a_i$ have to be $>1$

Comment: @Wouter True, haven't read that carefully, however it would be an even cooler example for induction if $a_i=1$ were allowed.

Comment: 1 is not stable, 2 is not stable... could this be a trick question? Are there *any* stable numbers?

Comment: I guess 3 is a stable number cause (1/2) + (1/3) + (1/6) = 1... Therefore all numbers >=3 are stable

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out it is about induction. I'll give you a hint about the induction step.

Assume that $k$ is stable. Then we have $a_1, \ldots a_k$ with $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{a_i} =1$.
Now we can simply change these number a bit, such that we have $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{a_i} = \frac{1}{2}$. Then we make a "smart" choice of $a_{k+1}$ and have that also $k+1$ is stable.
You must add some proof, that the new $a_i$ are all distinct.

If this is not sufficient to help you, please ask.

Comment: I have found k+1 as stable.... But how do I find all the stable numbers

Comment: @MayankMishra You just start with one stable. For example if you knew that 1000 is stable, than you know automatically that 1001 is stable as well. And than induction takes of (from 1001 you get 1002) etc.
The part that is left is finding one number that is stable. The smaller the better. Finally proof that all the other numbers are not stable.
By the way: 1 is stable, however 2 is not, you have to think about what goes wrong with the induction there.